# WPF Rectangle CommandBinding MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, commandbinding

I have the following problem
I have a lot of rectangles(or a paths) and I want to add a command to every rectangle, that when I click the rectangle an object will be fill with the values of the rectangle(color,name).And from the GUI I want to change the color of the rectangle when I execute the command
How can I do that in MVVM?

For example I have an object Ractangle

```cs
public Class Rectangle{
        String name;
        String color;

   public String Color{
      get{ return color;}
      set {color=value;}

      OnPropertyChange(color);
}

  public String Name{
      get{ return name;}
      set {name=value;}
      OnPropertyChange(name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you wrapped your Rectangle into a Button which gives you the readily usable Command property you can bind a command to. To be honest though I'm not 100% sure what you're after, please elaborate your scenario.

Comment: I have 5 rectangles and five circles.When I click on any of them I want to appear in a text box there name, and in a combobox there color.When I change the selected item in the combobox i want only the selected rectangles to change it's color

Comment: OK, I'd still recommend wrapping your rectangles and circles into a Button, otherwise you have to wire up the mouse click handling and command mapping manually in code behind which is not pretty. Or if you also want to do multiple selection, you could put them into a ListBox in which case you can do pretty much all you want to do in the ViewModel!

Comment: I'm sorry i am begginer.How can I wrap the rectangle in a button?  All my rectangles are designed in Illustrator.I have import them in expression blend

Comment: You'll have to create a Button style / template which is almost empty (only a ContentPresenter) and put those Rectangles inside them as content. This way they'll still look the same, but have all the functionality of a Button, much simpler / cleaner than having to implement all this yourself. Check this tutorial out to get more explanation: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/02/04/getting-started-with-wpf-4-button-controls-part-1-%E2%80%93-the-button-is-a-content-control

Comment: Thank You for the link and for the explanation

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as accepted with the little tick to the left! :) Also feel free to come back and post another, more specific question if you get blocked somewhere along the line!